# SQL subqueries to get info from a diff table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So basically, im new to SQL doing practice tutorials to better expand my knowledge. But i im stuck on this few problems.

How would i write and SQL query to

Get the cities  of  agents  booking an  order   for a   customer    whose   cid is  'c006'.

&

Get the cids    and names   of  customers   who did not place   an  order   through agent   a03.

WITHOUT USING THE "JOIN" method.

Database snapshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XicJh.png

Comment: Hint:   `FROM Orders JOIN Agents ON Orders.aid = Agents.aid`   Read up on using `JOIN` directives.

Comment: @OllieJones How can i do this without using the JOIN method.

Comment: Any updates about your solution? I would like to know if my solution helped you mate. @DI Kwame

Comment: Yes it did, you was very helpful. Im just stuck on this new problem: Get the pids of products NOT ordered by any customers who placed any order through agent a05.

Comment: Try selecting as answer, then make another one for your new problem. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you need to use join queries, your first query:

```
select a.city from Orders o 
inner join Agents a on a.aid = o.aid
where o.cid = 'c006'
```

The second one is similar, using the other tables and fields.

Comment: How can i do this without using the JOIN method as that is the rule.

Comment: sql allows to make an implicit join: select a.city from Orders o, Agents a where a.aid = o.aid and o.cid = 'c006', but is similar as making the explicit join. No other way to do it.

Comment: Im confuse. How did you get "a.city" and "Orders o" etc. Pretty much this extra letters.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you, you mean the 'a' and 'o'??, in SQL you can assign a shortcut for table names, so instead of using in "... Agents where Agents.aid = Orders.cid..." you can do "Agents a where a.aid = ..."

Comment: Oh ok i get it! THANKS!. Lastly, how can i do the same thing without using the JOIN method.

Comment: There's only two ways of doing your consult, the first one is in my original answer, the second one is "select a.city from Orders o, Agents a where a.aid = o.aid and o.cid = 'c006'". They are nearly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate:

```
-- Q1
SELECT city FROM agents
WHERE aid IN (
    SELECT aid FROM orders
    WHERE cid = 'c006'
); 
-- Q2
SELECT cid, name FROM customers
WHERE cid NOT IN (
    SELECT cid FROM orders
    WHERE aid = 'a03'
);
```